# Increasing Hough Line Accuracy/Segmentation of Book Spines via OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to do a segmentation based on the spines of the book. I have been having problems for quite a while. The two images below is an example of an unsuccessful segmentation using Hough Lines. I am trying to draw a line in between all the books.

I have also tried HoughLineP, which actually render worse results. I tried tweaking all the parameters of both HoughLine and HoughLineP. But I cannot seem to improve the detection rate. or even worsen the wrong detection.

[image]
[image]

I wish to ask if anyone have any ideas how to segment the book spines out? I had tried pre- processing methods, but it merges book spines of the same colour together, I was thinking of trying to search for black lines in the middle of the books since it tends to be slightly darker, but if you look at the book of seth godin and cutting edge advertisement, I cannot see any gap between them.

Rectangle detection won't work well too considering that some book spines have 2 different colour, forming a small rectangle of their own, for instance the cutting edge advertising book. I also have tried finding the contours which did not have good result either.

The final program i am looking to do is counting the number of books there is. but to do that, first of all I need a clean and successful segmentation.

Have anybody got any other methods that I can try? I would greatly appreciate all feedback, comments and answers. I have been stuck at this for more than a month already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that your spines will always be aligned vertically within the image, it would make sense to use an edge detection filter that detects only vertical lines. That will reduce some of the noise from detail on the spines themselves (titles etc) and give the Hough transform a greater chance of success.

A convolution filter such as this could be used:

```
-1 0 1
-1 0 1
-1 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it today and let you know the result. However, I wish to ask for like same book colour stacked together like the seth godwin book and the cutting edge advertisement book, the canny edges failed to seperate this two books as shown in the question. Any idea how I can make the Canny more effective to seperate them?

Comment: My point is to avoid [Canny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) detection as it will find edges at all angles. You're only interested in vertical edges, so a different filter can isolate those. You can use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) to experiment with different types of edge detection yourself. The image you uploaded is a dithered GIF which is not suited to edge detection because it has a lot of noise. Is your input image a GIF?

Comment: Nope. My input image is all PNG or JPEG files, the image uploaded in the question is a GIF though. Thanks for suggesting Gimp. I am checking it out now. I will experiment the different filters and hope to get back to you soon should it work, been busy with school lately. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment than answer, but...

Make sure to take out the edge found after detecting each one and repeat the edge detection. 
Also you can inspect the peaks for their relative strength and repeat only when its more difficult to pick out.

Lately I've been doing edge detection in a nonlinear way by finding the gradient in all eight directions and taking the max of those as the output for each pixel. Then repeating for each of the color when its a color picture. This is easy in Matlab but I'm not familiar Visual Studio.

Have fun!

Comment: I am also exploring image processing in MatLab now. Still a greenhorn in regard to MatLab. Do you have an example/tutorial/code that I can refer to? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have code or Matlab currently but just make use of the matrix manipulation then Matlab's algorithms will take over. Though there is a processing time improvement for multi processor computers that has to be turned on in Matlab. This is in the Matlab help file for the image processing package... maybe the hough transform function help page will point to it.

Comment: In python only using four points instead of eight, Edges = max(numpy.abs(A[0:-1,0:-1,:] - A[0:-1,1:,:]),numpy.abs(A[0:-1,0:-1,:] - A[1:,0:-1,:]),numpy.abs(A[0:-1,0:-1,:] - A[1:,1:,:]),numpy.abs(A[1:,0:-1,:] - A[0:-1,1:,:])) then maxEdges = max(A[:,:,0],A[:,:,1],A[:,:,2]) where A is the image as an array aka matrix in this case.